# native transport (git:// URL) for bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I was trying to install a python package via pip using a git url and stumbled across this.

According to the man page for git clone:

> Git supports ssh, git, http, and https protocols
> The native transport (i.e. git:// URL) does no authentication and should be used with caution on unsecured networks.
>
> The following syntaxes may be used with them:
>
> o ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
>
> o git://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/

I have no issues when I clone a Github public repo using the native transport scheme.

```
git clone git://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife -v
Cloning into 'Spoon-Knife'...
Looking up github.com ... done.
Connecting to github.com (port 9418) ... 192.30.253.113 done.
remote: Counting objects: 16, done.
remote: Total 16 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 16
Receiving objects: 100% (16/16), 2.25 KiB | 2.25 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), done.
```

However, if I try it with Bitbucket it gets stuck trying to connect on port 9418.

```
git clone git://bitbucket.org/teamsinspace/documentation-tests.git -v
Cloning into 'documentation-tests'...
Looking up bitbucket.org ... done.
Connecting to bitbucket.org (port 9418) ...
```

If I try the ssh scheme - `git clone ssh://bitbucket.org` - then it works as expected.

Does bitbucket not support cloning via `git://` url?

Comment: It doesn’t look like it, and there’s not really much reason to use `git://`. SSH/HTTPS overhead is small and beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

> Does bitbucket not support cloning via `git://` url?

No it does not (see [issue 2508](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-2508)), which means you must set a configuration to force using https or ssh urls instead of `git://` ones.

```
 git config --global url."https://bitbucket.org".insteadOf git://bitbucket.org
 # or
 git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org".insteadOf git://bitbucket.org
```

Comment: Nit: you posted the Bitbucket Server issue tracker, but Bitbucket Cloud links. The BB Cloud issue on this is https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11899/not-able-to-use-git-protocol-url which is marked as "wontfix".

Comment: @JimRedmond I know: it was to illustrate an issue that applies also on BitBucket server. In both cases, they won't open a special port (9418) to allow non-authenticated access to repos.

Comment: No worries - wasn't sure if you'd noticed.